# Every native call will get uncaught:Exception caught:(TypeError):Cannot call method 'xxx' of undefined

Tags: cordova, mgwt

my configurations are:

```
Ubuntu server 14.04 64 bit
GWT 2.7
Cordova 5.4.1
Andorid SDK Manage 24.04.1
Andorid SDK Tools 24.04.1
Andorid SDK Platform-Tools 23.1
Andorid SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2
Andorid 5.1.1(API 22) SDK Platform
```

and I downloaded the gwtphoneget showcase from here

```
https://github.com/vipulz/gwt-phonegap.showcase
```

and got it running in browser(by super dev model),then compile it,and followed this:

```
https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial
```

created a standard cordova project,and added andorid platform,copied showcase folder ,showcase.html and some resources files to a cordova project' www folder,renamed showcase.html to index.html,and added

`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

before

`<script type="text/javascript" src="showcase/showcase.nocache.js"></script>`

then cd to platforms/andorid,run

```
cordova run android
```

then an app has been installed to my phone(running **android 4.4.2**)

It seems that all gwt/js stuff works,I can click menus to corresponded views,but all native call doesn't work,for example,cliking ACCELEROMETER,jump to corresponded view then clck [Start] button,it will give an Alert:

```
uncaught:Exception caught:(TypeError):Cannot call method 'watchAcceleration' of undefined
```

and actually each native call will give similar error,what did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I found that after plugin get installed(like below),corresponded function worked

---

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera